# Code only works with breakpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm storing values from database in session like this:

```
private List<Message> _AllMessages = null;
        public List<Message> AllMessages
        {
            get
            {
                _AllMessages = Session["AllMessages"] as List<Message>;
                if (_AllMessages==null)
                {
                    Session["AllMessages"] = LoadMessages();
                }
                return _AllMessages;
            }
            set
            {
                Session["AllMessages"] = value;
            }
        }
```

When I access AllMessages like this:

```
AllMessages.Where(y => y.Created.Date == DateTime.Today).ToList();
```

I receive the following error:

```
Value cannot be null.
```

But when I put breakpoint on the `AllMessages.Where` line it looks like it evaluates AllMessages as Null for a second but then fetches values and everything works fine. Why does this happen?

Comment: is there a null entry in the list of messages?

Comment: What does LoadMessages look like?

Answer (score 1):

i think you have error, try this:

```
public List<Message> AllMessages
        {
            get
            {
                _AllMessages = Session["AllMessages"] as List<Message>;
                if (_AllMessages==null)
                {
                    Session["AllMessages"] = LoadMessages();
                    _AllMessages = Session["AllMessages"];
                }
                return _AllMessages;
            }
            set
            {
                Session["AllMessages"] = value;
            }
        }
```